# Symfony Always Include Route Default Values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-routing

So basically I am trying to achieve this: [New in Symfony 4.3: Always Include Route Default Values](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-always-include-route-default-values)

I have a **task** entity, which has multiple states like ***new***, ***open*** & ***closed***.

For this reason I am trying to generate a route `/tasks/new` `/tasks/open` `/tasks/closed`.
However, if there is no option set in my route, I want it to use `new` as default and also add it to the url.

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/tasks/{!status?new}", name="app_tasks")
 */
public function tasks(TaskRepository $taskRepository, string $status)
{
    $tasks = $taskRepository->findBy(['status' => $status]);
    return $this->render('tasks/index.html.twig', ['tasks' => $tasks]);
}
```

However this results into not a single matching route.

```
/tasks/new  => no route found  => should work
/tasks/open => no route found  => should work
/tasks      => no route found  => should work & route should be /tasks/new
etc.
```

The main issue seems to be the `!` before `status`. If I remove it entirely, everything works as expected, except that the route for `new` tasks looks like `/tasks` and not like `/tasks/new` - what I actually want.

I already tried to clear my cache - not working though. Symfony version is 4.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33224).
 This will likely be fixed in newer releases.

As for now try using the following:

```
@Route("/tasks/{!status}", name="app_tasks", defaults={"status": "new"})
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can use 2 routes for the same method. One with the slug, one by default if not caught.

Or you can check with a basic `if` in the controller depending on the slug of your main issues .